# Minimize the Word once you opened the Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Excel-VBA, you can minimize the Excel Application once you opened the Workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
End Sub
```

In Word-VBA, I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
End Sub
```

It should be minimize the Word Application once you opened the Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Contrary to the Excel documentation, the Word documentation of the
>   Application.WindowState property says that the windows state can only
>   be set with an active window:

Unhandled Exception gave a best description about the Application.WindowState.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some testing I got it running, but it's a bit strange. It seems to be a timing problem.

## This works:

Using `DoEvents` two times always works in my tests.
Only one `DoEvents` is not enough.

Info from Microsofts documentation about `DoEvents`:

> Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    DoEvents: DoEvents

    Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
End Sub
```

## That doesn't work either:

So I thought about adding a delay by using the API procedure `Sleep` and call this and `DoEvents` in a loop. But it didn't work.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim index As Integer
    For index = 1 To 5
        DoEvents
        Sleep 50
    Next index

    Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the Excel documentation, the Word documentation of the `Application.WindowState` property says that the windows state can only be set with an active window:

> The state of an inactive window cannot be set. Use the Activate method to activate a window prior to setting the window state.

So maybe you try to call `Application.Activate` first and see if that helps.

Comment: It didn't work. It gives you an error once you opened the document. `Run-time error '4601': Cannot activate application`

Comment: I suspect you can't access the document in the document open event because until the event is finished the document isn't open.

Try 'my_doc = Documents.Open(filename:=path_to_document, visible:=false)'

Comment: Then if you also want to minimise word use 'my_doc.Application.Activate=false'